# Working with 10+GB dataset in Python Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataset, hdf5

I have a very large .csv (which originally came from a SAS dataset) that has the following columns:

```
target_series  metric_series        month   metric_1  metric_2  target_metric
1              1                    1       #float    #float    #float
1              1                    2       #float    #float    #float
...
1              1                    60      #float    #float    #float
1              2                    1       #float    #float    #float
1              2                    2       #float    #float    #float
...
1              80000                60      #float    #float    #float
2              1                    1       #float    #float    #float
...
50             80000                60      #float    #float    #float
```

As you can see, the file has `60` months times `80000` independent series times `50` target series worth of rows, and takes over 10 GB of space when saved as a `.csv`
 .  What I need to do is perform and record a correlation between each `metric_1` and `metric_2` with the `target_metric`.

I have written the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")  # approximately 10 GB 
output = []

for target_num in range(1,50):
    for metric_number in range(1,80000):
        startTime = datetime.now()  # Begin the timer
        current_df = data[(data['target_series'] == target_num) & (data['metric_series'] == metric_number)]  # Select the current 60 months period that we want to perform the correlation on
        print('The process took: '+str(datetime.now() - startTime)+' hours:minutes:seconds to complete.')  # Stop the timer
        results_amount_target = current_df[['metric_1','target_metric']].corr()  # Perform metric_1 correlation
        results_count_target = current_df[['metric_2','target_metric']].corr()  # Perform metric_2 correlation

        output.append([target_num, independent_number, results_amount_target.iat[0,1], results_count_target.iat[0,1]])  # Record the correlation in a Python list will be converted to a DataFrame later
```

The reason that I have the `datetime` code in there was to find out why this process was taking so long.  The timer code is wrapped around the `current_df` line which is by far the slowest (I have played around with the placement of the `datetime` to find out why this was taking so long.

I found that selecting part of the data with this line of code:

```
current_df = data[(data['target_series'] == target_num) & (data['metric_series'] == metric_number)]
```

takes 1.5 seconds each time.  This is way too slow for me to do this process!  Clearly something needs to change!

I decided to try a different approach.  Since I know that I want to iterate through the dataset 60 lines at a time (for each `target_series` and `metric_series` pair) I would try one of two things:

1. Read in the top 60 lines from `data.csv`, perform the correlation, and then read in the next 60 lines from `data.csv`, with the following code `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=60,skiprows=60)`.  While this is faster for the first part of the dataset it gets unbearably slow as I have to keep skipping over the dataset.  It took over 10 minutes to read in the last 60 lines in the dataset on my PC!
2. Read in the top 60 lines from the `DataFrame` stored in memory with something like `data.head(60)` and then delete that data from the dataframe with `data = data.drop(data.head(60).index)` but this was even slower!

At this point, I'm exploring using `HDFStore` or `h5py` to move the dataset from `.csv` to a `.h5`, but I am unsure how to proceed.  The computer I'm doing this analysis on only has 16 GB of memory, and in the future I can expect to be working with data that is even larger than this file.

What's the best way to solve this problem, and how can I prepare to work with even larger data in Python / Pandas?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to `filmor`, I have rewritten my code to be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", chunksize=60) # data is now an iterable
output = []

for chunk in data:
    results_amount_target = chunk[['metric_1','target_metric']].corr()  # Perform metric_1 correlation
    results_count_target = chunk[['metric_2','target_metric']].corr()  # Perform metric_2 correlation

    output.append([chunk['target_series'][0], chunk['independent_series'][0], results_amount_target.iat[0,1], results_count_target.iat[0,1]])  # Record the correlation in a Python list will be converted to a DataFrame later
```

This is now super fast and memory light!  I would still appreciate if someone could walk me through how to do this with `HDFStore` or `.h5` files.

Comment: Have you tried using the builtin chunking of `read_csv`? In any case, you'll be better of using HDF5 or something similar.

Comment: I will try the chunking of `read_csv`, but algorithmically, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: You could parallelize with a `multiprocessing` process pool. The main process would read the file and pass the starting offset for a chunk of data to a worker who would read that chunk (`f = open(filename);f.seek(offset);pd.read_csv(f, nrows=60)`) and return the calculated value.

Comment: @tdelaney I will definitely look into that.  For now, however, @filmor has shown me the great power of `chunking` with `read_csv`

Comment: You may need to switch to something larger scale like DataFrames in Spark - https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html