# Get the last 10000 lines of a csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, tail

In pandas, I can just use `pandas.io.parser.read_csv("file.csv", nrows=10000)` to get the first 10000 lines of a csv file.

But because my csv file is huge, and the last lines are more relevant than the first ones, I would like to read the last 10000 lines. However, this is not that easy even if I know the length of the file, because if I skip the first 990000 lines of a 1000000 line csv file using `pandas.io.parser.read_csv("file.csv", nrows=10000, skiprows=990000)` the first line, which contains the file header, is skipped, as well. (`header=0` is measured after `skiprows` is applied, so it does not help either.)

How do I get the last 10000 lines from a csv file with a header in line 0, preferably without knowing the length of the file in lines?

Comment: Are you on a Linux or OSX system? If so, then using `tail -n 10000 file > file2` will probably be the easiest...

Comment: Hitting on @Carpetsmoker 's idea, if you insist on using `Python`, you can call that on `subprocess.call()` :P

Comment: @Carpetsmoker but he also need a header. It should be as `head -n 1 file > file2; tail -n 10000 file >> file2`

Comment: @AntonProtopopov How about even shorter `head -1 file > file2; tail -10000 file >> file2`. I gained four keystrokes.

Answer (score 7):

You could first calculate your size of the file with:

```
size = sum(1 for l in open('file.csv'))
```

Then use `skiprows` with `range`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=range(1, size - 10000))
```

**EDIT**

As @ivan_pozdeev mentioned with that solution you need to go though file twice. I tried to read whole file with pandas and then use `tail` method but that method slower then suggested.

Example dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000000,3), columns=list('abc')).to_csv('file.csv')
```

**Timing**

```
def f1():
    size = sum(1 for l in open('file.csv'))
    return pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows=range(1, size - 10000))

def f2():
    return pd.read_csv('file.csv').tail(10000)

In [10]: %timeit f1()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.8 s per loop

In [11]: %timeit f2()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.94 s per loop
```

Comment: Note: this goes through the entire file twice. Not that I (readily) see a better way...

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I thought that with `pd.read_csv('file.csv').tail(10000)` it'll be faster but from timing it's a bit slower..

Comment: With `tail`, I surmise, you first read _all_ the data into a `DataFrame`, then take a slice. Not only is this slower, you risk running out of memory.

Comment: If anyone wondered. I thought that bigger problem probably is the temporary list that is the size of the "large file" but pandas explodes the integer into a list anyways.

Comment: It depends on the size of the file.  If you have enough memory to slurp in the file without swapping, it will be faster.  But once swapping hits you, everything will be slow.  For a scalable solution, you want to find a way which works acceptably even with really big files. But then again, if you expect the majority of files to be small enough to fit into memory, you might want to find a balance where you use a faster algorithm where it's possible, and then fall back to the scalable algorithm when the input is too big.

Comment: @tripleee `tail` will underperform much faster than RAM limit. `tail` solution fully parses while data set while skipping rows just needs to properly track delimiters. That's a serious edge. `tail` will have chance only if the number of actually skipped lines to read is relatively small, making the initial pass basically just an overhead.

Comment: @luk32 I'm sure you are correct; I am reasoning about the general case, and am not familiar with the internals of Pandas.

Comment: `size = sum(1 for l in open('file.csv',encoding="utf8"))`
The encoding was needed in my case, otherwise I got an error about an unknown character.

Answer (score 4):

Using @Anton Protopopov sample file. Reading in a partial bit of the file and the header in separate operations is MUCH cheaper than reading the entire file.

Just directly read the final rows

```
In [22]: df = read_csv("file.csv", nrows=10000, skiprows=990001, header=None, index_col=0)

In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
               1         2         3
0                                   
990000 -0.902507 -0.274718  1.155361
990001 -0.591442 -0.318853 -0.089092
990002 -1.461444 -0.070372  0.946964
990003  0.608169 -0.076891  0.431654
990004  1.149982  0.661430  0.456155
...          ...       ...       ...
999995  0.057719  0.370591  0.081722
999996  0.157751 -1.204664  1.150288
999997 -2.174867 -0.578116  0.647010
999998 -0.668920  1.059817 -2.091019
999999 -0.263830 -1.195737 -0.571498

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Quite fast to do this

```
In [24]: %timeit read_csv("file.csv", nrows=10000, skiprows=990001, header=None, index_col=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 262 ms per loop
```

Pretty cheap to determine the length of the file a-priori

```
In [25]: %timeit sum(1 for l in open('file.csv'))
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop
```

Read in the header

```
In [26]: df.columns = read_csv('file.csv', header=0, nrows=1, index_col=0).columns

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
               a         b         c
0                                   
990000 -0.902507 -0.274718  1.155361
990001 -0.591442 -0.318853 -0.089092
990002 -1.461444 -0.070372  0.946964
990003  0.608169 -0.076891  0.431654
990004  1.149982  0.661430  0.456155
...          ...       ...       ...
999995  0.057719  0.370591  0.081722
999996  0.157751 -1.204664  1.150288
999997 -2.174867 -0.578116  0.647010
999998 -0.668920  1.059817 -2.091019
999999 -0.263830 -1.195737 -0.571498

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to take *exactly* the last N lines is [as per Anton Protopopov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35979742/648265), first go through the entire file, counting the lines.

But for the next step, taking them, optimization can be made (which `tail` does):

- as you go, save offsets of lines in a circular buffer of length N. Then at the end, the oldest item in the buffer will be the required offset. Then all it takes is an `f.seek()` on the file object as per [Working with 10+GB dataset in Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882588/working-with-10gb-dataset-in-python-pandas).

A much faster way that doesn't include going through the entire file would be to *not require an exact number of lines:* from what I can see, you only need *an arbitrary large amount.* So, you can:

- get a rough estimation of the offset you need to seek to (e.g. calculate/estimate the average length of a line)
- seek there, then to the next (or the previous) line break

  This requires extra caution if you can have data with embedded line breaks: in that case, there's no fool-proof way to detect which quotes are opening and which are closing. You have to make assumptions about what can and what cannot be inside/outside quotes... and even how far to look for a quote to find out if the line break is embedded!

Answer (score 0):

You can try [tail](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.tail.html) from pandas, it returns last n rows

```
df.tail(10000)
```